# cmd file executes but does not start server when opened with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: express, batch-file, cmd, forever, windows-task-scheduler

Basically what I want is to start an express.js server with forever on startup Windows. I've created a .cmd file with commands (see below). When I double click on this file the server starts and works like a charme. However, when I create a task in Windows 10 Task Scheduler with a trigger on "Logon User", the cmd window opens, does something (cannot see console so quickly) and closes. No server started.

This is the code in the .cmd file

```
cd\
cd Users\Jan
timeout /T 5
forever start forever.json
```

- User is administrator
- Tried a timer in the cmd file
- Tried to delay the trigger by 5 mins. in Task Scheduler

Does anyone has a clue why this works on double click file and not when opened by Task Scheduler?
Is there a better way to start this server with forever?

Comment: How have you configured the batch file to run? you need to configure it to run `cmd.exe` with the arguments `/c c:\Mypath\to\batchfile.cmd` and then use the start in option with the same start path ``c:\Mypath\``. I would also not do all the cd to profiles. instead start it directly in the script `forever start C:\users\jan\forever.json`. If `jan` is your user then even better `forever start "%userprofile%\forever.json"`

Comment: Thanks Gerhard and Mofi. I've been reading through the pages and with my limited knowledge I still did not get it to work. My cmd file now looks like this: `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm"
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\forever.cmd" start forever.json`. And in the Task Scheduler script `"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"` wit an argument `/c %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\ForeverStart.cmd`. (I've moved the cmd file to another directory). Again on double click it works, but not when asked for by Taks Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in the fact that the full path needs to be used in de command lines. I've checked the .json file and changed the relative paths to full paths also and now it works.

However, when I use the command `forever list` forever does not show any forever processes running. Nevertheless my server is running. Thanks all!